# Using printf in java

Tags: java, printf, system.out

Following the format below..

`System.out.printf("%.2f", val);`

Was wondering how i could get my output to be 2 decimal places to the left side not to the right? I am trying to compute monthly interest rate. My formula in my class method is:

- Annual Rate is set at 4.5 it cannot be changed so i have it set to: private static in my separate class.
- Formula for monthlyInterest `return (annualInterestRate / 12) * balance;`

Then when i go back to main and try and print as follows: 
`"\nAnnual Rate:\t" + String.format("%.2f", a.getAnnualRate())`

Results

```
ID:       1122
Created:      03/02/14
Owner:        Tom H
Opening Balance:  $100.0
Annual Rate:      4.50
Monthly Interest: 37.5 <-----Would like this to display the monthly interest properly
```

Comment: What do you think the proper output should be?

Comment: .375 Decimal place moved 2 places to the left

Comment: `printf` will not change the value.  If you want it to print a different value, then compute the correct value.  In your case, probably you need to divide something by 100.

Comment: Is there an easier method to formatting???

Comment: @javaaaaaa as said by @ajb, it is NOT formatting (at least not in Java).  If you want to display 37.5, then give a value of 37.5.  Easiest way is to do `System.out.printf("%.2f", val * 100)`

Comment: Again: use `System.out.printf("%.02f, yourDoubleVariable);`...

Comment: Right, but id like to keep the 4.5 as the annual rate display and just format my monthly interest output to be moved 2 places to the left so the user knows how much monthly interest they're paying on that particular balance. Dont know why im not getting this :/

Comment: op please don't confuse the rest of us. "Move 2 places to the left" is actually dividing by 100, period.

Answer (score 0):

[Yes, you can format your output](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) either by using `System.out.printf()` or by using `System.out.format()`.

```
Monthly Interest: 37.5 <-----Would like this to display the monthly interest properly
```

Now, in comments you mention `0.375` and then you show `37.5` here. Surly, the unit in which the value is represented will change, bear that in mind.

Comment: @ajb arp.. my bad :D Never answer questions when half awake.

Comment: @ajb "cast the value to an `int` and if that gets you a zero, multiply your `double` with `100` " ?? :-P

Comment: I don't know what the OP really wants.  But a formula that multiplies the value by 100 in some cases, and not in others, is almost certainly wrong, because then the value won't be in a consistent unit.